# How do I parse JSON children using JSON.NET?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I’m trying to get the results in `textures: […]` in JSON obtained from
http://t0.rbxcdn.com/ca063a6bab4e145de481384a8a62d64f and display it in a listbox.

I have this code:

```
Public Class ReturnObject
    Public Property Url As String
    Public Property textures As String
    Public Property obj As String
    Public Property mtl As String
    Public Property Final As Boolean
End Class
```

```
Dim input2 As String = obj.Text
Dim json2 As ReturnObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of ReturnObject)(input2)
obj.Text = HttpGet("http://www.roblox.com/thumbnail/resolve-hash/" + json2.obj)
mtl.Text = HttpGet("http://www.roblox.com/thumbnail/resolve-hash/" + json2.mtl)
```

But I get the error

> Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'textures',
>   line 1, position 313.

Comment: Heya, I accidentally clicked publish before I was done writing the post. I added the rest of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textures` is an array in the JSON, containing one string (mind the brackets*):

```
"textures":["bff5714f0b959385663b1fe030b87064"]
```

You can reflect that in your class structure (mind the brackets**):

```
Public Class ReturnObject
    Public Property Url As String
    Public Property textures As String()
    Public Property obj As String
    Public Property mtl As String
    Public Property Final As Boolean
End Class
```

<sub>* they’re square brackets</sub>
<sub>** they’re parentheses</sub>

Comment: Okay so what if I wanted to do this? texture.Text = (json5.textures) would that work

Comment: @user3851593: What is `texture`? If it’s a multiline textbox or label, for example, use `String.Join(Environment.Newline, json5.textures)`. If it’s a listbox as stated in your question, you’ll need to modify the `Items` collection, not the value of the `Text` property.

Comment: Texture is a richtextbox. I just tried doing that and I got `code'{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}'`

Comment: Inspect your values in the debugger, then. Which one is `Nothing`? `json5`? `json5.textures`?

Comment: Where does `json5` come from? Is it perhaps missing `textures`? You’ve used `json2` in the question, after all.

Comment: I just changed it around. All I did was rename json2 to 5. Now I'm getting this error 'Error `code 2 Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String`